# shell script to run update sql statement

Tags: sql, linux

I have an update sql statement and I have to run this sql script through linux script.. What will be the shell script to do such a task?

```
update inventories
set reserveddate is null,
     purchasedid is null,
where purchased is null
and (TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'HH24') - TO_CHAR(reserveddate ,'HH24')) > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql -uroot -p<YOUR_PASS> -e <DB_NAME> "update inventories set reserveddate is null, purchasedid is null, where purchased is null and (TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'HH24') - TO_CHAR(reserveddate ,'HH24')) > 1;"
```

Comment: thank you. How can we do the same thing in Oracle database?